# How to send a request using suds client with multiple elements in the request

Tags: python, sax, suds

I am having an issue sending a suds request.

I sent a request to a different method just using the following:

```
from suds.client import Client

   client = Client(wsdlurl)

   client.service.Login(name, employid)
```

This came back with the correct response as name and employid are direct children elements of Login.

But how can I send a request using the below:

```
 <soapenv:Body>
      <v12:getStuff>
         <v12:stuffSelect>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <v12:stuffIDs>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <v12:num></v12:num>
            </v12:stuffIDs>
         </v12:stuffSelect>
      </v12:getStuff>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The reason for this is so I can add a dynamic value into num

I've tried it like this:

```
return self.client.service.getStuff.stuffSelect.stuffIDs(**{'stuffID': stuff_id, })
```

But get this error

```
AttributeError: 'Method' object has no attribute 'stuffSelector'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds. It is essential you know your wsdl interface; suds can provide it partly at run-time:

```
# ... 'client' via wsdl url, login

# get example
http_status, payload = client.service.your_wsdl_get_stuff_method()
stuffIDs = []
if http_status == 200:
    for stuff_id in payload:  # depending on your wsdl
        stuffIDs.append(stuff_id)

# upload example
stuffSelect = client.factory.create('stuffSelect')  # structure generated by suds from wsdl
stuffSelect.your_wdsl_stuff_ids_name = stuffIDs  # (maybe debug to see your name)

params = foo, bar, stuffSelect
svr_response = client.service.your_wsdl_upload_method(*params)
```